# System Preferences NSImage not resolving

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsimage, system-preferences

I can't seem to get my NSImages to resolve in my System Preferences project?

The image is a user.png that resides in my main folder of my xcode project.

EDIT: I have included a link to the [Source Code](http://cl.ly/0t2h0y2n203U0t0M3Q3v). Hopefully someone is able to spot the problem.

**PersonController.m**

```
- (id)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn row:(NSInteger)row {
    Person *person = [personsList objectAtIndex:row];

    if (tableColumn == listGender) {
        if ([person.gender isEqualToString: @"m"]) {
            /****************************
             *  Method - 1: Doesn't work
             ****************************/
            NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"user.png"];
            NSLog(@"image is valid? %@", [image isValid] ? @"yes" : @"no");
            return image;


//            return @"male";
        }
        else {
            /****************************
             *  Method - 1: Doesn't work
             ****************************/
            NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"user_female.png"];
            NSLog(@"image is valid? %@", [image isValid] ? @"yes" : @"no");

            return image;
//            return @"female";
        }
    }
    else if (tableColumn == listName) {
        return [person valueForKey:@"name"];
    }
    else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Also, specifying this path works, but why do I have to specify the entire path?

```
NSImage *myImage = [[NSImage alloc] initByReferencingFile:@"/Users/coderama/sandbox/Persons/user.png"];
```

Comment: You'd better to use `mainBundle` as in my answer below if you want have your app working on other macs

Comment: I thank everyone for their suggestions, but unfortunately none of them worked. Please see update to the source code... hopefully someone will be able to spot the problem. Also +1 for everyone who helped

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reach image file in your project folder by this way:

```
NSString *imagePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"smiley" ofType:@"png"];
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
NSImageCell *cell = [[NSImageCell alloc] init];
[cell setImage:image];
```

Comment: Use `setImage` method instead of `setObjectValue`. Look the answer, I updated it

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to use the correct name of image. If image is "Smiley.png" then use "Smiley.png". Also you should use extension with method `imageNamed`. Try:

```
NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"smiley.png"];
```

and doublecheck if file is really all in small letters.

Answer (score 1):

Does the `smiley.png` file show up in the Xcode project navigator? If it isn't it won't get added to the built application. Drag it into the navigator from Finder and deselect "Copy Items into destinations...". [image: Drag]

If it is in the Navigator check the Target Membership. Click the file in the navigator and open the Utilities Pane. Make sure the checkbox is checked for your application on the first tab. [image: Target Membership]

Answer (score 0):

Though I have not checked your code I would like to suggest you these steps:

**Step 1:** In XIB drag and drop NSImageCell onto listGender table column.

**Step 2:** In `- tableView:objectValueForTableColumn:row:`

return nil, when tableColumn == listGender

**Step 3:** Implement this method:

`– tableView:willDisplayCell:forTableColumn:row:`

and set image on the cell, when tableColumn == listGender

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I just tried this and it doesn't work. Have a go with the attached zip file in my original post...